# cs50 readability doesn't compile

Tags: c, cs50

Can someone explain me why it doesn't compile?
what did I forget?
Something went wrong when I wrote the condition statements.
most of time I had comparison pointer integer(char and char *) error or comparison a string literal is unspecified error()

[compiler error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD4j0.png)

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void)
{   
//Getting input from user
string s = get_string("Text: "); 
printf("%s\n", s);

int letters = 0; // count letter
int words = 1; // count words, words +1 because 5 spaces = 6 words
int sentences = 0; // count sentences 

for( int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
{
    if((s[i] >= "a" && s[i] <= "z") || (s[i] >= "A" && s[i] <= "Z"))
    {
        letters++;
    }
    
    if(s[i] == " ")
    {
        words++;
    }
    
    if(s[i] == "!" || s[i] == "?" || s[i] == ".")
    {
        sentences++;
    }
}
printf("letters %i\n", letters);
printf("words %i\n", words);
printf("sentences %i\n", sentences);
}
```

Comment: Don't post pictures of text but post text as properly formatted text. (Your error log is text that can be copy/pasted).

Comment: The `int words = 1;` initialization is almost certainly wrong, even with the opaque comment after it.  You can have leading or trailing spaces, or multiple spaces between words.

Answer (score 3):

When you use s[i] you are extracting the character (type char) which is an element of the string, so you have to compare it to characters.

In C you have to use single quotes for them:

```
s[i] == 'a'
```